# One submit button, two redirections to php files

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a final year project and I have one form which is uploading a file and as soon as upload button is clicked I need this form to do two actions for me which are:

1. redirect to upload.php file which stores the file in a database
2. redirect to email.php file which sends the emails

At the moment i can do either one of the above depending on the form action..

The code is as follows:
index.php
`

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">Upload</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['success']))
{
?>
<div align="center">
</label>File Uploaded...<a href="view.php" class="button">Click to View</a></label>
</div>
<?php
}
else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
{
?>
<label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
```

This form is called in email.php and upload.php as:

```
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{   
    doSomething;

}
else 
{
    doSomethingElse;
}
```

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: HTML forms can not have 2 actions, so simply put your server login in a single file, or use 'include' or 'require' of the other file in the first one.

Comment: why don't you use a chain of responsibility pattern and route this request likewise: Form=>insert into Database=>send Email

Comment: This code does not constitute a reasonable attempt to solve your own problem, __doSomething/doSomethingElse__ hence it looks more like a ___do it for me request___

Comment: For me, the real question is:
Do you want to simply perform multiple php scripts after the form has been submitted, or redirect the *user* from page to page?
If it's the first, Ron Dadon's comment works. If not, you'll simply have to store the form data and re-send it with the redirect.

Comment: Remember, if you redirect from `email.php` before moving the uploaded file somewhere. The file will no longer be in the `tmp` location as when `email.php` terminates, it will delete the uploaded file from the temporary location

Comment: I hope you don't just allow any file to be uploaded then executed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

You should set a $variable before your if conditions.

Like that :

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
$condition1 = true;
} {
$condition1 = false;
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {
$condition2 = true;
} else { 
$condition2 = false;
}
```

And then do your jobs.

```
if ($condition1 && $condition2) {
//send email + upload
} else if (!$condition1) {
//error upload
} else if (!$condition2) {
//error mail
}
```

But I think it's not allowed to do a GET / POST action in same time.